# Adding clone element values with quantities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a quote generator, and I have a product field that's cloneable.

Each option in the select tag has a value, but there is a quantity next to the product, so that the user can select a product and how many they want.

The field is also clone-able so that the user can have multiple products each with their own quantities.

I need to take the quantity for each row, multiply it by the value of the option and add all the rows together to give a total.

This is what I have so far

HTML

```
<select class="form-control onChangePrice add product" name="Product">
       <option value="">Select...</option>
       <option value="3300">Product 1</option>
       <option value="4500">Product 2</option>
       <option value="6000">Product 3</option>
       <option value="8000">Product 4</option>
</select>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <input class="form-control onChangePrice productQuantity" type="number" name="ProductQuantity" value="1">
 </div>
```

Javascript

```
  $(".onChangePrice").change(function(){
    var productTotal = 0;
    $('.product').each(function(){
      if (this.value != "") {
        productEachTotal = this.value * $(".productQuantity").value;
        productTotal += parseFloat(productEachTotal);
      };
    });
   console.log(productTotal);
  });
```

But its just returning NaN.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: `$(".productQuantity")[0].value` or `$(".productQuantity").val()` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .val() to get the value.

```
$(".onChangePrice").change(function(){
    var productTotal = 0;
    $('.product').each(function(){
      if (this.value != "") {
        productEachTotal = this.value * parseInt($(".productQuantity").val());
        productTotal += parseFloat(productEachTotal);
      };
    });
   console.log(productTotal);
  });
```

Comment: This is still just returning NaN frustratingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
function calculateRowTotals(rowSelector, productSelector, quanitySelector) {
  let rows = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(rowSelector));
  return rows.map(function(rowElement) {
    var product = rowElement.querySelector(productSelector);
    var quantity = rowElement.querySelector(quanitySelector);
    if(!quantity || !product) return 0;
    return parseFloat(product.value || 0) * Math.abs(parseFloat(quantity.value || 0));
  });
}

function calculateTotal(rowSelector, productSelector, quanitySelector) {
  return calculateRowTotals(rowSelector, productSelector, quanitySelector).reduce(function(total, rowTotal) {
    return total + rowTotal;
  }, 0);
}



// demo code

[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.onChangePrice')).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    console.log('rows total: ', calculateRowTotals('.row', '.product', '.productQuantity'));
    console.log('total: ', calculateTotal('.row', '.product', '.productQuantity'));
  });
});

console.log(calculateTotal('.row', '.product', '.productQuanity'));
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <select class="form-control onChangePrice add product" name="Product">
         <option value="">Select...</option>
         <option value="3300">Product 1</option>
         <option value="4500">Product 2</option>
         <option value="6000">Product 3</option>
         <option value="8000">Product 4</option>
  </select>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <input class="form-control onChangePrice productQuantity" type="number" name="ProductQuantity" value="1">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <select class="form-control onChangePrice add product" name="Product">
         <option value="">Select...</option>
         <option value="3300">Product 1</option>
         <option value="4500">Product 2</option>
         <option value="6000">Product 3</option>
         <option value="8000">Product 4</option>
  </select>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <input class="form-control onChangePrice productQuantity" type="number" name="ProductQuantity" value="1">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will this work with cloned elements? If I cloned my product 50 times over, would it keep working for the amount I have cloned?

Comment: If you clone the rows yes, it only works for 1 product and 1 quanity per row. But you can easily make it work for n products per row and n rows.